# I'm beginner and try to re-write java code to Kotlin, using canvas, try write a circle. But as a result I get only blank screen on my Device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

This is my SplashScreen.kt file:

```kotlin
class SplashScreen(context: Context): View(context) {
    private var paint: Paint? = null
    private var cx : Float = 0.0f
    private var cy : Float = 0.0f
    private var radius : Float = 0.0f

    fun SplashScreen(context: Context) {
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.GREEN
        paint.strokeWidth = 2.0f
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        cx = 200f; cy = 200f; radius = 50.0f;
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (paint != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(cx,cy,radius,paint)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Main.kt file:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var splash : SplashScreen

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val splash = SplashScreen(this)
        splash.keepScreenOn = true
        setContentView(splash)
    }
}
```

When I run my code on my device I get only white blank screen. With out any Circle.
I try call ActivityMain ,instead SplashScreen, with "Hello world" all its work.

I can't understand what I'm getting wrong here.

Can anyone tell me why this just produces a blank screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are confusing yourself with the constructor and another method named `SplashScreen`

You could simplify your code significantly using the following:

```
class SplashScreen(context: Context): View(context) {
    private val paint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.GREEN
        strokeWidth = 2.0f
        isAntiAlias = true
    }
    private val cx : Float = 200.0f
    private val cy : Float = 200.0f
    private val radius : Float = 50.0f
    
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx,cy,radius,paint)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an additional constructor to allow for values to be set

```
class SplashScreen(context: Context): View(context) {
    private val paint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.GREEN
        strokeWidth = 2.0f
        isAntiAlias = true
    }
    private var cx : Float = 0.0f
    private var cy : Float = 0.0f
    private var radius : Float = 0.0f

    constructor(context: Context, radius: Float, cx: Float, cy: Float) : this(context) {
        this.radius = radius
        this.cx = cx
        this.cy = cy
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx,cy,radius,paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. But I don't understand why this code work and code under doesn't work.
They're look quiet similar

Answer (score 0):

I found problem in your code.
So you made wrong constructor.
you should replace constructor code.
you can use constructor keyword.
So like this.

```
class SplashScreen: View {
    private var paint: Paint? = null
    private var cx : Float = 0.0f
    private var cy : Float = 0.0f
    private var radius : Float = 0.0f


    //fun SplashScreen(context: Context) { // this is wrong
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) { // this is correct.
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.GREEN
        paint.strokeWidth = 2.0f
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        cx = 200f; cy = 200f; radius = 50.0f;
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (paint != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(cx,cy,radius,paint)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't use `super(context)` here

Comment: No, we can use super(context) in here. Please look top. I changed class declaration. `class SplashScreen: View {`

Comment: Ah, I see, then it makes slightly more sense in that case to use it as the primary constructor. But thanks for clarifying

Comment: I try to change my code to code above, and I steel get white screen without circle.
Maybe something wrong with my ActivityMain.kt??